# Solving a recursive relationship

Tags: recurrence-relations, problem-solving

I was wondering whether the following relationship could be solved.

$$S_0= 100, C=(0.05, 0.15,...), P = (0.03, 0.05, ...), D = 120, R = 0.08\\
S_1 = S_0(1-C_1)\left(1-P_1-\frac{1}{D + 1}-(1-R)\right)\\
S_2 = S_1(1-C_2)\left(1-P_2-\frac{1}{D + 1}-(1-R)\right)\\
S_3 = ...$$

Notice that the $C_1$ refers to the first element in the $C$ vector and $P_1$ refers to the first element in the $P$ vector, while $D$ and $R$ are constants.

I have tried to come up with a part, but I can't seem to solve the latter part, which is in the latter brackets.

$$S_n=S_0\cdot\Pi_{i=1}^{n}(1-C_i)\cdot ...$$

But the latter part, I am not sure how to do it, except just writing it out, but then I am still stuck unfortunately. I have the feeling that it can be solved, but I am not sure how.

Please do not solve the $C$ and $P$ they can be random and are considered user input, so they can vary arbitrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be possible to solve this recurrence relation. The first thing to do is find out an expression for $C_n$ and one for $P_n.$ I get
\begin{align*}
C_{n+1}&=0.05+0.1n \\
P_{n+1}&=0.03+0.02n.
\end{align*}
The recurrence relation we can write as
\begin{align*}
S_{n+1} &= S_n(1-C_{n+1})\left(1-P_{n+1}-\frac{1}{D + 1}-(1-R)\right) \\
&=S_n(1-(0.05+0.1n))\left(1-(0.03+0.02n)-\frac{1}{121}-0.92\right) \\
&=S_n(0.95-0.1n)\left(0.05-0.02n-\frac{1}{121}\right).
\end{align*}
This is a difficult recurrence relation to solve, but Mathematica comes through with the following:
$$S_n=\frac{1919}{121}\, 4^{-n} 125^{1-n}
    \left(-\frac{17}{2}\right)_{n-1}
    \left(-\frac{263}{242}\right)_{n-1}, $$
where the symbol $\displaystyle\left(-\frac{17}{2}\right)_{n-1} $ is the [Pochhammer](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html) symbol.